# creating unsigned bigint field in django model

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models

I am using python 2.7, Django 1.9.4 on Ubuntu 14.04

While defining model, I couldn't find a way of creating a field of type UNSIGNED BIGINT.

I checked the documentation. I don't think there is something like this which seems surprising. Maybe I am missing something.

Then I checked the source at:
[https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.9.x/django/db/models/fields/**init**.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.9.x/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py)

Line 1883... class BigIntegerField is actually a signed vaue.
Line 912... AutoField is an Integer

Then I found a (hackish) way to do it (I am not sure if it would break something later):
[Can the Django ORM store an unsigned 64-bit integer (aka ulong64 or uint64) in a reliably backend-agnostic manner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10678102/can-the-django-orm-store-an-unsigned-64-bit-integer-aka-ulong64-or-uint64-in-a)

PS: The master branch has something called BigAutoField at line 993.. but it is also signed.
[https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/**init**.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py)

What would be your advice to create this field?